# Need Date Conversion in AngularJs Controller

Tags: angularjs, date, controller

Could anyone please suggest me how to convert date from this 1387843200000 format into this 23rd April,2017  inside my controller?
I tried with the following code

```
duedate=1387843200000
date = $filter('date')(duedate, "dd MMM, yyyy");
```

It gives me the date like 23 Apr,2017. But I want like 23rd April,2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the miliseconds to date first by

```
var miliseconds = 1387843200000;
var date = new Date(miliseconds);
```

and then you can use `momentjs` for format the date based on what you like. If you want change based on your question, then just do something like this

```
date = moment(date).format('Do MMM, YYYY')
```

or if you want to know more the format, you can open 
[momentjs website](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Convert 1387843200000 to be a javascript date and bind using angularJs like :

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope) { 

  $scope.changedDate= new Date(1387843200000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller = "ctrl">
    <span>{{changedDate | date : 'medium'}}</span>
  </div>
</body>
```